# How to detect animateCamera did finish on the Google MapView using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to execute API request when animate camera did finish.

What is the way to get signal, that animate camera did finish animating?

Below is code how I am using animateCamera.

```
GoogleMapController mapController;

// … setting up MapView and GoogleMapController 

CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: position, zoom: 12.0);
mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: i said that onCameraIdle  is called when the camera mouvement is finish , the animation in dont know

Comment: @Merym Thanks. You can post an answer. It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCameraIdle is called when the camera mouvement is finish ,

```
 GoogleMap( onCameraIdle: _onCameraMoveEnd,....)

_onCameraMoveEnd() {
    setState(() {
    //todo
    });
  }
```